# Xindy (imakeidx, XeLaTeX) not sorting correctly

Tags: xetex, languages, xindy, imakeidx

Being new to `LaTeX`, I would appreciate help on this particular problem.

Somehow `xindy` does not recognise languages on my system. I am on Windows, have a recently downloaded `MiKTeX 2.9`, use `TexMaker`, run `XeLaTeX` (tried both with and without `--shell-escape` / `--enable-write18` option), all my `.xdy` files for languages seem to be in place, no warning or error is issued, but no matter which language I switch to, the sorting comes out wrong. Note that with `XeLaTeX` I cannot use `inputenc`.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
    \setdefaultlanguage{croatian}
\setmainfont{Cambria}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[columns=1]

\begin{document}

avion\index{avion}
buka\index{buka}
cura\index{cura}
čarapa\index{čarapa}
dug\index{dug}
džem\index{džem}
nos\index{nos}
nježan\index{nježan}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

So, the accented letter is placed under 'A'.
When I turn the `xindy` option off, I get this:

[image]

This time it placed the accented letter at the end of the alphabet.

In Croatian, 'č' is a separate letter, so it has to be listed under its own heading, while 'dž' and 'nj' are compound letters that should stand after 'd' and 'n', respectively.

What I want to get is sorting like this:

> A
>
> avion
>
> B
>
> buka
>
> C
>
> cura
>
> Č
>
> čarapa
>
> D
>
> dug
>
> Dž
>
> džem
>
> N
>
> nos
>
> Nj
>
> nježan

The same thing if I use Czech, or Spanish (e.g. ñ) - they just don't group correctly in the index.
Is there a simple solution to this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass Xindy the language options. Run with `xelatex -shell-escape`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\setdefaultlanguage{croatian}

\makeindex[columns=1,options=-M texindy -L croatian -C utf8]

\begin{document}

avion\index{avion}
buka\index{buka}
cura\index{cura}
čarapa\index{čarapa}
dug\index{dug}
džem\index{džem}
nos\index{nos}
nježan\index{nježan}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have realized that I can enforce pdflatex to run xindy specifying `\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M texindy -L croatian -C utf8]`.  However the problem is that IDX and IND should be in another folder than TEX file; i.e. "build\name.idx" and "build\name.ind".  Is there any solution to send texindy this information?

Comment: @Pygmalion I recommend not using separate directories for auxiliary files and now you can understand why.

Comment: Hm, in the end I do need to write a batch file anyway, because I must replace `|hyperindexformat{\see`s that cannot be digested by `xindy`.  To bad that the language setting cannot be passed from `pdflatex` to `xindy` within `index.idx`, so I have to create batch files for each language separately.